# Jersey CORS configuration to allow response cookies from server

Tags: rest, cookies, spring-boot, jersey, kotlin

I have a Jersey REST interface that I want to send cookies in its responses to each request but no cookies are ever present in any response.

I have a feeling it's a CORS issue and I'm not sure what CORSResponseFilter configuration I need to allow cookies to be set and successfully sent in a response.

My project is built with SpringBoot under Kotlin.

Response code:

```
@POST
fun put(): Response {

    val cookie = NewCookie(Cookie("RESERVATION", "TEST"),
            "Session", 60 * 60, false)

    return ok()
            .cookie(cookie)
            .entity(Result("OK", "Success"))
            .build()
}
```

Filter code:

```
open class CORSResponseFilter : ContainerResponseFilter {
    override fun filter(req: ContainerRequestContext?, res: ContainerResponseContext?) {
        res?.headers?.add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
        res?.headers?.add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET")
        res?.headers?.add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "origin, content-type, accept, authorization")
        res?.headers?.add("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "Set-Cookie")
        res?.headers?.add("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true")
    }
}
```

Requests are successful and the responses send otherwise as intended but all without any cookies. Prior to setting up the response filter I was able to receive cookies in each response.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: what are you using for requests sending?

Comment: @ledniov I am using `unirest` for javascript.

Comment: have no problems using such code: `unirest.post('http://localhost:8080/test').end(response => console.log(response.cookies));` . Do you have any additional configuration you haven't mentioned?

Comment: This is not a unirest issue. This is a CORS filter configuration issue under Jersey. I can use Postman, requests, XHR or any other form of http request service, unirest is redundant here. The problem is having the correct filter to allow cookies in the response from the server.